# Django Middleware that redirects to https

Tags: django, django-middleware

I'm trying to build some middleware in my Django project that redirects the user to a 'https' link if their request isn't initially to https. The code below is not redirecting the user under any of the tests that I've run (i.e. user enters 'www.example.com', 'http://example.com,', http://www.example.com', etc.

Can any of you spot the problem with this code? Normally, I'd use print statements to see what the path is being set to, but I can't do that on my live server (or at least I don't know how to):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class RedirectMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):

        host = request.get_host()

        if host == 'www.example.com' or 'example.com':

           path = request.build_absolute_uri()
           domain_parts = path.split('.')

           if domain_parts[0] == 'http://www':
               path = path.replace("http://www","https://www")
               return HttpResponseRedirect(path)

           elif domain_parts[0] == 'www':
               path = path.replace("www","https://www")
               return HttpResponseRedirect(path)

           elif domain_parts[0] == 'http://example':
               path = path.replace("http","https")
               return HttpResponseRedirect(path)

           elif domain_parts[0] == 'example':
               path = path.replace("example","https://www.example")
               return HttpResponseRedirect(path)

           else:
               pass

       else:
           pass
```

Thanks again guys

Comment: I think you should redirect users using web server (Nginx, Apache) not using middleware

Comment: Ok. I believe you that I should use Nginx or Apache to do this, but can you explain why?

Comment: There's a setting for that: [`SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT).

Comment: Look, first of all every single request passes through web server and then it goes your application(django in your case) so if you will redirect user in first step you will save some resources(no need to parse url, write logic etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your settings file

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/middleware/#ssl-redirect

You'll also need to add the following to your middlewares

```
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
```

It's a settings available from Django 1.8+

Comment: When I try this, I get an error indicating that there are too many redirects, then an Error 503. Any idea why?